# How do I find files by *error* condition in the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I know that using `find . -exec <command>` returns all of the files which return a success condition for that command. How do I make it so that I can find all things which have errors?

My basic use case is that I'm trying to find files which fail a basic syntax check. If I were looking for files which were valid PHP, I would do something like

`find . -exec php -l {} \; -print`.

How do I get the opposite of that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `!` or `-not` option to invert the truth of the next test.  So, for the example you give, it would be

```
find . ! -exec php -l {} \; -print
```